# BIND9 DNS Records not Propagating

Tags: bind

Kind of new to managing DNS via BIND.

We have a setup with a master server and a slave server. I've updated the zone file on the primary name server for our domain but the changes aren't propagating over to the secondary server. The funny thing is that I'm making a change in the zone file for a different domain on the server and those changes ARE being propagated to the secondary server.

Anyway I can force the change to be made?

Also, there was a third nameserver that used to be operational but has been offline for a few months now. I removed it from the zone file for the two domains that have it listed as a name server and it still (over 24 hours later) shows up from time to time when I run a record check.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Nate

Comment: did you modified the serial number of your zone file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Every time you make a change to a zone file you should increment the serial (most people make the serial YYYYMMDDNN, where NN is the revision *that day*).
2. Slaves can get notifications upon update, but it generally has to be configured, otherwise you can usually do a `rndc refresh example.com` on the slave and it will pull.
3. NS records have to be updated both in the zone file and at the registrar.
4. DNS records can be cached, sometimes for weeks, and largely depending on how you have your zone configured. If you do not want your records to be cached, modify the TTL and such.

Comment: 5. `NS` records can be used to delegate authority for subdomains, but this cannot be done at the top of the zone. (i.e. a "re-delegation" of a zone is illegal) The `NS` records at the top of the zone are used for identifying the nameservers that notifies should be sent to by default, so attempting to "re-delegate" a zone breaks this. Stub zones are an exception, but they're also an advanced concept.